# Make CGI-script work (Apache, Python, MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, apache

Could you help me read some strings from MySQL and show them in my web browser.
This is just for my localhost.

I receive the following:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

As for my file hello.py, it is situated here:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/test1.my/www/cgi-bin# ls -l
total 8
```

It's properties are as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 465 Nov 2 23:30 hello.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 186 Nov 2 15:59 hello.py~
```

Could you give me some hint what to fix?

[These are my configuration files](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!109&authkey=!AC8_eLcI60sJGcg)

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? If so, do they show anything?

Comment: Also, what does hello.py contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you need to output an empty line after writing your `Content-Type`-header in `hello.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"                  
#   newline after headers!    ^^ 
print "<html><head><title>Книги</title></head>"
...
```

Also, you should check the apache error logs (usually at `/var/log/apache/error.log`) to get more information about the error.

Comment: These are logs and renewed hello.py https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!108&authkey=!APXrRUNfT3ltdYg

Comment: There was something about encoding there. I replaced everything. Now English only.

Comment: [...01:14:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/test1.my/www/cgi-bin/hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
[Sat Nov 03 01:20:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/test1.my/www/cgi-bin/hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
[Sat Nov 03 01:20:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: hello.py

Comment: @Kifsif: "No module named MySQLdb" is your problem

Comment: @Kifsif - you don't need to change everything to english, just declare your encoding (I've added that to the example). And in your second hellp.py you're still missing that newline after the headers, and of course the `MySQLdb` module